# Remove duplicates after filtering by foreignkey

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am currently writing a flask webapp. I have 2 tables, 1 for users and 1 for book titles. I have a foreignkey in book titles to relate it to the user who entered it. I want to remove duplicates but only on a per user basis (aka, each user can have the same title associated with them, but I don't want a duplicate title for one user)

How can I remove duplicates (or better yet, update old entry with new date) based on first sorting by the user.id (foreignkey)?

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to attempt the solution ?

Comment: A basic table schema of the two tables would be extremely helpful along with any code you're already attempted. I'm curious why you are allowing duplicate books in the book table, but this is something that could generally be solved by a GROUP BY book id and then using an appropriate aggregate clause for the user id (sort by most recent addition, etc.).

Comment: @AK47 No attempt yet unfortunately as this is where I'm stuck :(

Comment: @JasonBaumgartner Is there a better way than allowing duplicate books? I want multiple users to be able to have the same book in their "library" in their profile.

And thanks. I'll try and see if that gets me on the right direction

Comment: It depends how far you want to go with normalizing your database. It sounds like you need a user table to keep all your unique users in, a book table to keep all your unique books in and a table relating user to book. That table would have user id, book id, when the entry was added, etc.

Comment: @JasonBaumgartner It's not their books. It's a list of books they want to read. So I have a User table (with things like id, username, email, profile_picture, etc), and a Book table (with id, book title, and user_id as a foreignkey).

Then users can input the book they want to read, and someone else can have the same book they want to read. I just want to be able to make sure someone doesn't add the same book twice.

Comment: Right. You need a table just for books and a table that associates users with books. So if a book does't exist and I am a new user, I might get a user id of 123 and I may enter a book 456. You need to check if the book exists in the book table and if it doesn't, put the book in that able (only one row per unique book) and then go to the user_book table and put in my user_id and book_id along with the date of when I added the book. That way you avoid duplicates in your book table. Right now your DB sounds a bit denormalized.

Comment: @JasonBaumgartner Oh, thank you! I think that makes sense now!

Comment: @JasonBaumgartner Does that mean that my user_book table is just two foreign keys (user id, and book id)? And then a date of course? So 3 columns?

Comment: @CUbuffsFTW The sqlalchemy idioms for what you are trying to do are thoroughly explained [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many). Read the `Many to Many` and `Association Object` sections.